# Is the ICOC trinitarian?

Tags: trinity

ICOC is the "International Church of Christ". They are mainly charismatic.

Knowing their faith a little bit, I can't decide if they are. I can't remember the mention of the Trinity in their views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The International Church of Christ, has its origins in the Restoration Movement (sometimes called the Campbell-Stone movement). When it developed and then split from the churches of Christ group in the 1980s and 90s it retained the Trinitarian views of its background.

The London ICoC website: http://www.thelondonchurch.org//ChurchWide/ContentPage.aspx?PageTitle=Beliefs&Region=London notes in the "What We Believe" section -

> Number 1. There is one true God, the only God that exists, the God of Abraham, Jacob and the sons of Israel, who reveals himself to the
>   world as The Father, Son and Holy Spirit. (Deuteronomy 6:4; Isaiah
>   45:5; Matthew 28:19; 2 Corinthians 13:14).
>
> Number 2. Jesus of Nazareth is the prophesied Messiah, the Son of God and the one and only Saviour of humanity (Mark 14:62; John 1:29-34; Acts
>   4:12).
>
> Number 5. Rebirth and entry into the Kingdom of God is by repentance and baptism for the forgiveness of sins and the indwelling of the Holy
>   Spirit (Acts 2: 36-41; John 3:3-5; 1 Peter 3: 20-21; Romans 6: 3-7).
>
> Number 7. The life of the church is to be characterised by the fruits of the Holy Spirit, by each member’s individual devotion to Jesus Christ and
>   by the Christians’ corporate responsibility to one another (Galatians
>   5:16-25; Ephesians 4:1-3?).